# Imagechops subtraction and addition

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have two images. I subtracted first from the second and again added the difference to the first and saved the image. But the new image differs from the original image. Why is this so?
Here is the code:

```
import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

im1 = Image.open("scimg1.png") 
im2 = Image.open("scimg2.png")

diff = ImageChops.subtract(im2, im1)
newim2 = ImageChops.add(im1, diff)
newim2.save("newim2.png")
diff.save("diffimg.png")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see when looking at the arrays of the pixel values from im1, im2 and diff It seems as if the diff values never goes below 0 even if the pixel value of im1 is greater than the pixel value of im2.

So for example if the pixel value at one point for im1 is (255,255,255) and for im2 it is (235,235,235) the diff value will be (0,0,0) even though 255-235=-20. When you then try to add the diff value of 0 to im1 it will still result in a pixelvalue of (255,255,255) and not (235,235,235).

Also, the diff array seem to correspond to the size of im1's array, so if im1 is smaller than im2, the diff image will also be smaller. However I'm not really sure if it will be the same for you depending on what images you are using, I suggest you import numpy and view the arrays of your own pictures and the diff.